# different results with data frame and data table in r

Tags: r, data.table

I have a dataset with 13 millions rows which looks like this:

```
       dateInt secid         dret  weeknum
12470 20080107  2234 -0.021197471 20080107
12471 20080107  4533 -0.029914530 20080107
12472 20080107  5325 -0.013240986 20080107
12473 20080107  6048  0.007226014 20080107
....
22472 20080108 69343 -0.01158537 20080107
22473 20080108 69450  0.05555556 20080107
22474 20080108 69479  0.00000000 20080107
...
```

where `date` and `secid` are unique identifiers (and, while not quite relevant to my question below, `weeknum` is a value that can be common to many `date` values, e.g. `date = 20080107 or 20080108 or 20080109 or 20080110 or 20080111`).

Consider the following two functions (one for `data.table` and one for `data.frame`):

```
avefast<-function (x, ..., FUN = mean) {
    if (missing(...)) 
        FUN(x)
    else {
        g <- as.factor(paste(..., sep = "|"))
        split(x, g) <- lapply(split.default(x, g), FUN)
        x
    }
}

avefaster<-function(x,...,FUN=mean) {
  if (missing(...)) FUN(x) else {
    g<-as.factor(paste(...,sep="|"))
    dt<-data.table(x,g)
    setkeyv(dt,"g")
    as.data.frame(dt[,y:=FUN(x),by="g"])$y
  }  
}
```

Both `avefast` and `avefaster` are intended as faster versions of `ave` (both are only a tad faster than `ave`, `avefast` is typically 15% faster, and `avefaster` is typically 25% faster if measured using `system.time`).

I tried the following two functions - both to get the maximum value of `dateInt` within each `weeknum` and `secid` combination.

```
prcretw$retain<-avefast(prcretw$dateInt,prcretw$weeknum,prcretw$secid,FUN=max) 
prcretw$retain2<-avefaster(prcretw$dateInt,prcretw$weeknum,prcretw$secid,FUN=max)
```

In most cases `avefaster` gives the same answer as `avefast` (or `ave`) but for 11% of cases it gives the wrong answer and I can't figure out why. For example a typical case in my dataset is

```
dateInt secid          dret  weeknum         retain          retain2
...
20080107    191432  0.0119658120    20080107    20080111    20080110
20080108    191432  -0.0152027027   20080107    20080111    20080111
20080109    191432  -0.0145797599   20080107    20080111    20080111
20080110    191432  0.0182767624    20080107    20080111    20080111
20080111    191432  -0.0461538462   20080107    20080111    20080111

20080114    191432  0.0349462366    20080114    20080118    20080118
20080115    191432  -0.0294372294   20080114    20080118    20080118
20080116    191432  0.0240856378    20080114    20080118    20080118
20080117    191432  -0.0322299652   20080114    20080118    20080118
20080118    191432  -0.0072007201   20080114    20080118    20080118
...
```

In the result extract above, `avefaster` using `data.table` gave the wrong answer for `secid==191432` and `dateInt=20080107`.

Perhaps I using the `data.table` incorrectly. Would it be possible for someone to take a look at the code I posted above, particularly the `avefaster` function, and if there any possible errors point them out to me?

Thanks.

*** EDIT ***

Just an edit to an old post of mine. I found the issue. Whenever there is a key column in data.table which is `NA`, there seems to be wrong answers when doing `by` operations - even for cases where the key column is not `NA`. The data.frame approach above doesn't have this issue as all `NA` keys are grouped together. If we remove the `NA` keys from the data.table, the answers for `by` operations get corrected.

Comment: @Arun, the main thing I'm trying to do is to calculate the `max` value of `dateInt` for every combination of `weeknum` and `secid`. Also, I'm trying to gradually convert my code from `data.frame` to `data.table` - so my DT-DF-DT is a part of an eventual switch to DF.

Comment: Could you please post the raw data for `secid==191432`? Also, does this do what you want: `DT <- data.table(pcretw); setkey(DT, weeknum, secid); DT[, retain3 := max(dateInt, na.rm=TRUE), by=c("weeknum","secid")]`? Or maybe I am missing what you want to achieve.

Comment: In addition, with `data.table` I think it would be faster to use `:=` to generate your g variable (and making it `integer` or `character` may even speed things further that `factor`). Using `DT[][,y]` should also be faster than using `DT$y` but I can't point to a source at the moment. Do some benchmarking on your machine if speed is important.